# Evaluating integral $\int\frac{\sqrt{x- x^2}}{x^6}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{x- x^2}}{x^6} dx$

How to evaluate this integral? I tried many substitutions but all in vain. Is it a bad idea to use substitution here?
I want to solve it without using hyperbolic substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\frac1x$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sqrt{x- x^2}}{x^6}dx
=&-\int t^3(t-1)^{1/2}\>dt\\
=& -\int (t-1)^{7/2}+3  (t-1)^{5/2}+3  (t-1)^{3/2}+  (t-1)^{1/2}\>dt\\
=&-\frac29 (t-1)^{9/2} -\frac67 (t-1)^{7/2} -\frac65(t-1)^{5/2}
-\frac23 (t-1)^{3/2}+C
\end{align}

Comment: A much, much better answer. For the reference of others, the manipulation on the second line was: $$t^3(t-1)^{1/2}=(t-1)^{1/2}(t-1+1)^3=(t-1)^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{3}\binom{3}{n}(t-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^3\binom{3}{n}(t-1)^{n+1/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x-x^2=-\left(x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\left( 2x-1\right)^2\right)$ and so:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x-x^2}}{x^6}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}{x^6}dx$$
Now you can take the substitution $2x-1=\sin(u)$ and go to a trigonometric integral.

Comment: How is this any easier? A $\sin^6$ integrand is not a pleasant sight

Comment: @FShrike I don't know a shorter method. In general, when you don't know an easy method a nice idea is to go to a trigonometric equation to use Weierstrass substitution, which will always work (although it can be pretty long). In this case looking at the solution I dont think there will be an easy solution. The other solution given looks as tricky and cumbersome as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by parts with $f(x)=\sqrt{x-x^2}$ and $g'(x)=1/x^6$. Completing the square at the denominator and setting $u=2x-1$, you deal with some $\sqrt{1-u^2}$. At this point, $u=\sin(v)$ and then $w=\tan(v/2)$ gives traditional integral to solve.

Comment: which gives at the end $\dfrac{2\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{-\left(x-1\right)x}\left(16x^3+24x^2+30x+35\right)}{315x^5}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $$
x-x^{2} \geqslant 0 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1,
$$
we can use the substitution $x=\sin^{2} \theta$, $$
\begin{aligned}
I =2 \int \frac{\cos ^{2} \theta}{\sin ^{10} \theta} d \theta 
=2 \int \cot ^{2} \theta \csc ^{8} \theta d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $t=\cot \theta$ converts $$
\begin{aligned}I&=-2 \int\left(t^{8}+3 t^{6}+3 t^{4}+t^{2}\right) d t\\&= -2\left(\frac{t^{9}}{9}+\frac{3 t^{7}}{7}+\frac{3 t^{5}}{5}+\frac{t^{3}}{3}\right)+C \\& =-2\left[\frac{(x-1)^{\frac{9}{2}}}{9}+\frac{3(x-1)^{\frac{7}{2}}}{7}+\frac{3(x-1)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{5}+\frac{(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]+C\end{aligned} $$